# Dynamically change css in php?

Tags: php, css

I have a little question. Can I dynamically change (with php) content of the css style in this way?

```
<?php
               header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

               $color = "red;";

               ?>

               header      {

                           color:<?php print $color; ?>

                           }    

?>
```

Comment: Have you considered trying it?

Comment: Yes, but its not found. Problem is, that when use the file without <style> and <style> tags, i cant use the contextual help for css.

Comment: You need to rename your style file to end in `.php` or use `.htdocs` to parse `.css` files as PHP. As for cache, you just need to set that within headers.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know how

Comment: The problem is not that you can't change (with PHP) content of the css style in this way. Your problem is that your editor can't comprehend that and that ruins your comfy coding style. Which is your personal problem and not a CSS or PHP one. That's why my downvote.

Comment: Anyway this approach is sooo 2006 - check Less / SCSS / stylus.

Comment: If you only want to use variables in your CSS, you should consider to use LESS (or SASS etc.) http://lesscss.org/ Here you have additional advantages, like calculations of colors and nesting

Answer (score 4):

Sure it's possible, why not give a try?

Linking the php css in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/name-of-file.css.php">
```

and in your css.php file you put your code, but without the

```
<style type="text/css">
```

so it should look like this

```
 <?php
           header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
           $color = "red;";
           ?>

           header      {

                       color:<?php print $color; ?>

                       }
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but if you do not use the <style> tags, contextual help not found :/

Comment: problem is, that I need change css dynamically with my php and db. And I need change css properites with php, get from db and save into the db.

Comment: I can't see a problem there, type your PHP code in it and have fun. Did you even try it?.. I still don't get your problem.

Comment: @user2579395 Did it run?

Answer (score 2):

It is better you use your javascript to change the style between php tags.

for example:

```
if($response){

echo "<script>
    $('#matter_table').css('display', 'block');
</script>";
} else{

echo "<script>
    $('#matter_table').css('display', 'none');
</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
<?php
echo<<_CSS
<style>
body{
color:red;
}
</style>
_CSS; 
?>
```