# How to have a button change colour based on text file?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I'm making a web application and I want to have a status button change colour from red to green based on "on" or "off" in a text file. I'm using a Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu to "control" the Raspberry Pi. The text file is located on the Raspberry Pi and I make the web server read what's on the Raspberry Pi via code.

For turning the tv on/off I have these lines of code (on in this case)

```
        screen = screenDAO.findById(screenCode);
        String[] args = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "ssh pi@172.19.xx.xxx 'echo \"on 0\" | cec-client -s'",
                "with", "args" };
        try {
            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File f = new File("/tmp/status.txt");
        if(f.exists()){
            f.delete();
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        File file = new File("/tmp/status.txt");
        FileWriter fr = null;
        BufferedWriter br = null;
        try {
            // to append to file, you need to initialize FileWriter using below constructor
            fr = new FileWriter(file, true);
            br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                br.newLine();
                // you can use write or append method
                br.write("on");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
                fr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

For updating the button's status I currently have

```
        screen = screenDAO.findById(screenCode);
        String[] args = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c",
                "ssh pi@172.19.67.177 /tmp/status.txt", "with", "args" };

        try {
            Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/status.txt")));
            if (content.contains("on")) {
                System.out.println("The screen is turned on.");
                Boolean screenStatusOn = true;
            } else if (content.contains("off")) {
                System.out.println("The screen is turned off.");
                Boolean screenStatusOn = false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

This is what I have in js

```
    $('.screen-status').on('click', function(event) {
        var $onButton= $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url : 'updateScreenStatus',
            type : 'POST',
            data : "screenCode=" + $onButton.data('code'),
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(data) {
            },
        });
    });
}

function initScreenControls() {
    $('.screen-on').on('click', function(event) {
        var $onButton= $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url : 'turnOnScreen',
            type : 'POST',
            data : "screenCode=" + $onButton.data('code'),
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(data) {
            },
        });
    });

    $('.screen-off').on('click', function(event) {
        var $onButton= $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url : 'turnOffScreen',
            type : 'POST',
            data : "screenCode=" + $onButton.data('code'),
            success : function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(data) {
            },
        });
    });
}
```

I want the button to turn red when turning the tv off and green when it's turned on. Currently I only have it send "The screen is turned on." (or off) to the console.

Comment: How are you building your HTML? Add a class to the buttons there and hava  CSS for, say, `.button-off` or `.button-on` or whatever you decide.

Comment: Cant find any JavaScript / jQuery Code using Ajax here.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  Add inside the `success:` :  `$onButton.toggleClass("button-on", data == "The screen is turned on.");` would be better to return some JSON with status+message then you don't need to check the exact wording of the message.

Answer (score 0):

You could expand on what happens on success in the 'on-click' part of your  javascript code (below where you log the console).

e.g: (off example)

```
 $('.screen-off').on('click', function(event) {
    var $onButton= $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url : 'turnOffScreen',
        type : 'POST',
        data : "screenCode=" + $onButton.data('code'),
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            /*document.getElementById("OnButton").style.backgroundColor = "red"; */
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        },
        error : function(data) {
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: is there a particular reason why you want to set the style using php? If so look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32069113/1675954) (it basically echos out javascript to the same effect as is in my answer)